# Three tables join query not showing any data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables users, favorites and friends.

users : id, name, email

favorites : id, favorite_id, user_id

friends : id, friend_id, user_id

Query 1 : Joining tables users and friends

```
select 
friends.`friend_id`
from users 
left join friends on users.id = friends.`friend_id` 
where users.id != 18 
and (user_id = 18 or user_id is NULL) 
order by id asc
```

Query 2: Joining tables users and favorites

```
select 
  users.`created_at`
, users.name
, users.email
, users.`image`
, users.is_online
, favorites.`favorite_id`
, users.id
, user_id 
from users 
left join favorites on users.id = favorites.`favorite_id` 
where users.id != 18 
and (user_id = 18 or user_id is NULL) 
order by id asc
```

Both the above queries are working fine,

Now, what I want to do is join both the queries, I have tried something like this,

Query Tried:

```
select 
  users.`created_at`
, users.name
, users.email
, users.`image`
, users.is_online
, favorites.`favorite_id`
, users.id
, user_id
, (
   select 
     friends.`friend_id` 
     from users 
     left join friends on users.id = friends.`friend_id` 
     where users.id != $user_id 
     and (user_id = $user_id or user_id is NULL)
   ) 
from users 
left join favorites on users.id = favorites.`favorite_id` 
where users.id != $user_id 
and (user_id = $user_id or user_id is NULL) 
order by id asc
```

But, its showing no data,
Where, I am missing. Please help me out.

output from Query 1:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "friend_id": 2
        }
    ],
```

Output from query 2

```
"data1": [
        {
            "created_at": "2020-08-04 23:53:53",
            "name": "yashyashwi",
            "email": "yashyashwi@gmail.com",
            "image": "1596540233.jpeg",
            "is_online": 0,
            "favorite_id": null,
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": null
        }
      ],
```

Desired output :

```
 "datas": [
            {
                "created_at": "2020-08-04 23:53:53",
                "name": "yashyashwi",
                "email": "yashyashwi@gmail.com",
                "image": "1596540233.jpeg",
                "is_online": 0,
                "favorite_id": null,
                "friend_id": 2,
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": null
            }
          ],
```

Comment: what type of result you expect?

Comment: Sample data, desired results and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish would all help.  Also, an attempt to format the queries is appreciated.

Comment: When I run both queries, data is there. But, on joining them, no data is showing,

Comment: i.e. Query Tried is not working

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added the output, now check

Comment: Show desired output for a user which have 3 friends and 2 favorites.

Comment: I just want to add the output of qquery1 into query 2

Comment: and it will show in desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give *input* data. I reconstructed them. Check the list beginning at the top, with the `WITH` keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id INTEGER
, created_at TIMESTAMP
, name VARCHAR(32)
, email VARCHAR(32)
, image VARCHAR(32)
, is_online BOOLEAN
);
INSERT INTO  users VALUES (
    1
  , TIMESTAMP '2020-03-24 05:35:45'
  , 'yashyashwi'
  , 'yashyashwi@gmail.com'
  , '1596540233.jpeg'
  , FALSE
  );
  
  CREATE TABLE favorites (
      id INTEGER
    , favorite_id INTEGER
    , user_id INTEGER
    );
    
    INSERT INTO favorites VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL);
    
  CREATE TABLE friends (
      id INTEGER
    , friend_id INTEGER
    , user_id INTEGER
    );
    
  INSERT INTO friends VALUES (1,2,1);

select 
  users.created_at
, users.name
, users.email
, users.image
, users.is_online
, favorites.favorite_id
, friends.friend_id
, users.id
, favorites.user_id 
from users 
left join favorites on users.id = favorites.favorite_id 
left join friends on users.id=friends.id
where users.id != 18 
and (favorites.user_id = 18 or favorites.user_id is NULL) 
;
-- out  created_at |    name    |        email         |      image      | is_online | favorite_id | friend_id | id | user_id 
-- out ------------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----+---------
-- out  2020-03-24 | yashyashwi | yashyashwi@gmail.com | 1596540233.jpeg | f         |      (NULL) |         2 |  1 |  (NULL)
```

Comment: with is showing the error i.e. unrecognized statement type

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? MySQL has been supporting the WITH clause for a long time ...

Comment: Well, I changed it to a bunch of CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. Tested with a fiddle